# Getting Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float64 and Float32 using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, code-review

I'm trying to export sentinel-1 bands with this code in Google Earth Engine but I have recently this error. I didn't have this problem in the past. So here is the code.

The code:

```
var start = new Date("02/05/2015");
var end = new Date("03/05/2015");

  var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
      .filterDate(start, end)
      //.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
      // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
      //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
      .filterBounds(geometry);

var count = s1.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
  var img = ee.Image(s1.toList(1, i).get(0));
  var geom = img.geometry().getInfo();
  Export.image(img, img.get('system:index').getInfo(), {
    'scale': 20,
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'region': geometry.toGeoJSONString()
});
}
s1 = s1.toUint16();

Export.table(s1,'Sentinel1_csv');

print(Chart.image.seriesByRegion(s1, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),'VH')
.setOptions({title: 'VH mean value over time on R3'}));
```