# How to solve "Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64"

Tags: google-earth-engine

I get an error when attempting to export an image from Earth Engine:

> Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64

I checked these links:

- [Getting Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float64 and Float32 using Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333769/google-earth-engineerror-exported-bands-must-have-compatible-data-types-found?rq=1)
- [Getting Error: exported bands must be compatible from Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271311/gee-error-exported-bands-must-be-compatible?rq=1)

How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
var area = ee.FeatureCollection('users/wandygs8/municipal_boundaries');
var name = 'Batallas_Jan_March_2017-';
var period = 2018;
var version = 2;
var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var indices = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B11']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi);
};
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterBounds(area)
                  .filterDate('2017-11-01', '2018-05-01')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 100))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .map(indices);
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0, 
  max: 0.3, 
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 
};
var imagen = dataset.median();
var maxNDVI = dataset.select("NDVI").max().rename('ndvimax');
var minNDVI = dataset.select("NDVI").min().rename('ndvimin');
var meanNDVI = dataset.select("NDVI").mean().rename('ndvimean');
var desvNDVI = dataset.select("NDVI").reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).rename('ndvidesv');
var maxNDWI = dataset.select("NDWI").max().rename('ndwimax');
var minNDWI = dataset.select("NDWI").min().rename('ndwimin');
var meanNDWI = dataset.select("NDWI").mean().rename('ndwimean');
var desvNDWI = dataset.select("NDWI").reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).rename('ndwidesv');
var dem = SRTM.select('elevation').clip(area).rename('dem');
var CompImagen = imagen.addBands(maxNDVI).addBands(minNDVI).addBands(meanNDVI).addBands(desvNDVI).addBands(maxNDWI).addBands(minNDWI).addBands(meanNDWI).addBands(desvNDWI).addBands(dem);

Map.centerObject(area, 10);
Map.addLayer(CompImagen, rgbVis, 'Imagen S2');
print('Metadatos',CompImagen);
Map.addLayer(area,{color:'red'}, 'Area Estudio');
Map.addLayer(CompImagen.select('ndvidesv'),{},'DesvStandart');
Map.addLayer(CompImagen.select('NDVI'),{},'NDVI');
Map.addLayer(CompImagen.select('NDWI'),{},'NDWI')
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: CompImagen,
  description: 'iS2_'+ name + '_'+period+'_'+version,
  scale: 20,
  region: area
});
```

I must also export the algorithm training points in a shapefile for another job, how can I do it?